# How do i add libraries to CodeLite projects?

Tags: libraries, codelite

I recently started using CodeLite since i though that it would be a great software, but i don't know how to add libraries to projects.
Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 9):

> but i don't know how to add libraries to projects

Assuming that you want to compile and link against some external libraries, these are the steps you need:

- Open your project settings (right click on the project->settings) -> Compiler -> Include Paths, and set here the location where the compiler can find your `.h` files
- Open **project settings->Linker->Libraries search path** and place here the location where the linker can find the libraries (usually suffixed with `.a`, `.dll`, `.so`)
- Open the **project settings->Linker->Libraries** and set here the library name, for example `libMyFirstLib.a;libMySecondLib.a` etc

You can find more info here:
http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/ProjectSettings

The screenshots are outdated, but the names / fields are the same

Comment: Thank you, Glut still won't work because into his folder i couldn't find any .dll/.so/.a file but thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for to include igraph library, thanks!